# Boot Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS with no boot-loader

Tags: linux, bootloader

​​​I have Ubuntu installed on the hard drive next to Windows.
On the end of the installation, I had an error and Grub was skipped.
How can I boot this system with no bootloader?
Maybe we have some Boot CD detecting all installations in the system or something?

Comment: Google is trying to tell me that I need to install boot-loader, but maybe I can do this on USB or use some different solution like Grub alternative?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Please delete this question and try https://unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: You can go to unix.stackexchange https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516421/boot-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts-with-no-boot-loader

Answer (score 0):

GRUB from USB in Live Ubuntu. I will test it, you can find the answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516421/boot-ubuntu-desktop-18-04-lts-with-no-boot-loader